# Creating custom character using Java and assigning unicode to it

Tags: java, graphics, unicode, jframe, locale

I am working on music project and I want to use some special character(from Asian language - TELUGU) which can not be achieved using any of the unicodes provided in this link:

http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0C00.pdf

Can I create my own character using some way in java and assign some keyboard shortcut to it? Does Java provides ability to it? If not can anyone suggest the best way of implementing it. If there is no way doing this I am planning to use 2DGraphics provided by java and draw character on my applet window

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that I don't know any way to define a custom font in Java (which is what you'd do), but a much better solution is to use a font editor to create a standard TrueType where the required characters are defined. You can use this font in all kinds of applications, including your own :)